# unable to get process name with psutil

Tags: python, psutil

I'm using this to get the current processes. It does work on my machine, but it doesn't when I run it on another one.

```
for p in psutil.process_iter():
    try:
        proc_names[p.pid] = p.name()
    except psutil.Error:
        pass
for c in psutil.net_connections(kind='inet'):
# etc...
```

I'm getting this error

```
    proc_names[p.pid] = p.name()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

by using p.name, instead I get this

```
    for c in psutil.net_connections(kind='inet'):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'net_connections'
```

Comment: Bob, you test this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30180722/unable-to-update-python-package-psutil). you need update psutil.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your machine is using a newer of version of psutil (2.x) and the other machine is using a 1.x version.

Changing the p.name() to p.name was the right move, but I don't think net_connections exist in 1.x.  Try [get_connections](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/wiki/Documentation) instead or update psutil on the other machine

Comment: that is strange, because I just upgraded to the newest version

Comment: Have you verified the upgraded version by doing something like this print psutil.__version__ ?